# function tm::tm_map encounter an error

Tags: r, tm, mclapply

I have a `VCorpus` "oanc" and I want to change all the words to lower case, so I use the following function

```
oanc1 <- tm_map(oanc, content_transformer(tolower))
```

But I got a warning:

```
Warning message:
In mclapply(content(x), FUN, ...) :
  scheduled cores 2 encountered errors in user code, all values of the jobs will be affected
```

The `VCorpus` "oanc" is of size 586MB while "oanc1" is only 4MB. In addition, all the contents, except the first text, are broken, and when I run

```
writeLines(as.character(oanc1[[2]]))
```

I got

```
Error in FUN(content(x), ...) : 
invalid input 'O<8c><be>BĭĪ<e2>=<f3><81>̡@>9<c2>Au<b7>l<99><c5>u <c4>%<a0>[,<9c><93><b8><90>w<b7><97><f7>58<e3><d7>><91><bf>"~WD<cf>2<c3><84>1GQ<dd><ed>ـ\<e2><fb><f3><d3>X]<fe>5t!<9f><89>ٍdH<e3><d6>Zu<bc><e8><b6>_RS<f0><f7><81><eb>E<f0><bd>Ԗ2o<b4>G<a7><b9><d2><fc><8a><f2><89>3<a8>ؗ<d6><c0>.w,<l<b7>}<f8>J<8f><f1><f1>����{p<94><a3>x<9e><89><da>e'<8c><ca>}y<d1><ca>V<f7>v<c3>>S^`<9e><86><f1><b1>E<b8>)<cd>ꅹ<e5><ab><<80><eb><8e>z<d0>}<a3>C<86>(%r<86><f4><e3>i*<da>i V{<94>'<f6>i<f6><a7>{dh<d0>jG۾wO<dd>?<<f7>i<c5>c<84>G<dc>3<bb>-E<e9>L<b1><b6>XG<f5>F<81><97><b1><e5><de>ln<b1><d6><f5><f6><90> Ǆ<b2>/j<fc><d9>{£<83><f1><c5>;n7<bb>ɰEG<a9><b0><87>!<b5>5]9<b9><e6><fe>_Q<aa>U<a8><c0><cf>,<d9><dc>wܒ<ba>ɑ<f1>Q<c9>:r<e4><b4><ea>w<be>PCb' in 'utf8towcs'
```

Does any one can help me? My operating system is ubuntu 14.04LTS, and R version 3.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure the text is encoded in UTF-8 (if you can open the file in a text editor then you should be able to modify the encoding when you save it). If that doesn't fix the problem, then try adding the argument "mc.cores = 1" to the tm_map function.

Comment: Thank you @joshua, it turns out one file in the source directory is not text readable as you mentioned.